# Any way to "un-release" a node from MAAS?

Tags: maas, openstack

One of our Autopilot openstack nodes was accidently released from MAAS.  I cannot seem to find a way to "un-release" or bring the node back into a deployed state without re-deploying which I believe would overwrite the OS and thus the openstack services on the node.  At this point, I am nervous about experimenting too much as the cloud was already brought down by the release.  I recognize that MAAS is not necessary to keep the cloud running but I would like for it to continue managing the server.  I could possibly acquire additional hardware to JUJU move the services I guess, but that would not be easy, so I would prefer to just mark it as still "deployed" in MAAS somehow.  Any help is appreciated.